# POST in grails not working

Tags: rest, grails, post

Hi I am trying to do a POST in grails I have tried 2 different methods.
I am wanting to replicate this curl command:

```
 curl -F upload=@in.xml http://server.com/service.pl > out.xml
```

this command works fine.
What I have tried so far is the following:

```
  def actualInputFile = new File("/path/to/file/in.xml");


    def retval = [success: false, message: null];


        HttpClient postClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartPostMethod postMethod = new MultipartPostMethod('http://server.com/service.pl');
        postClient.httpConnectionManager.getParams().setSoTimeout(300000);

        postMethod.addParameter("upload",actualInputFile);

        int status = postClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        def data = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
         def returnedFile = new File("/path/to/file/out.xml");
            returnedFile.write(data);
```

this gives a 500 error

i have also tried:

```
  def actualInputFile = new File("/path/to/file/in.xml");

    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://server.com/service.pl' )
    println "START POST"
    def postBody = [upload:actualInputFile] // will be url-encoded

    http.post( body: postBody,
            requestContentType: XML ) { resp ->

        println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
    }
```

this just doesn't work at all.

The first one which gets a 500 uses depreciated methods.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to run this code from a controller, if so I recommend not using commons-httpclient as it pulls in many dependencies as in general unwieldy to work with. The recommended client to use with Grails is http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder

Your example can be written as:

```
def rest = new RestBuilder('http://server.com/service.pl' )
def resp = rest.post(url) {
   upload = new File("/path/to/file/in.xml")
}
println resp.status
```

Nevertheless if you MUST use commons-httpclient what would help is if you actually posted what the actual error was you are seeing. Just saying you get a 500 without posting the error message isn't too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing. It looks like from the Perl and Curl that you are trying to POST the XML to an API. Is that correct?

If so you can do that easily but you have to specify the header and build your api to accept XML and interpret it.

I may be misunderstanding however.